# passing values between composite controls

Tags: c#, composite-controls

I have a control : composite control that defines a button. The button calls a Command event and sets the value of another control's property, before making the control visible.

Both of these controls are instantiated within a container control before hand. I need to grab the value of the property in the second form within the CreateChildControls() method, however, this is not possible, why?

**Scenario:**

```
public class Main : CompositeControl
{ 
    #region fields
    private StepPersonal _stepPersonal;
    private StepFinancial _stepFinancial;
    #endregion

    protected override CreateChildControls()
    {
        this._stepPersonal = new StepPersonal { ID = "StepPersonal1", Visible = true };
        this.Controls.Add(this._stepPersonal);
        this._stepFinancial = new StepFinancial { ID = "StepFinancial1", Visible = false };
        this.Controls.Add(this._stepFinancial);
    }

    protected override Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        this._stepPersonal.RenderControl(writer);
        this._stepFinancial.RenderControl(writer);
    }
}
```

**StepPersonal:**

```
public class StepPersonal : CompositeControl
{
    #region fields
    private Button _checkDetails;
    #endregion

    protected override CreateChildControls()
    {
        this._checkDetails = new Button { ID = "CheckDetailsButton", Text = "CheckDetails", CommandName = "DetailsConfirmation" }
        this._checkDetails.Command += new CommandEventHandler(this.OnCheckDetails);
        this.Controls.Add(this._checkDetails);
    }

    protected override Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        this._checkDetail.RenderControl(writer);        
    }

    protected void OnCheckDetails(object sender, CommandEventArgs args)
    {
        string argument = args.CommandArgs.ToString();

        this.Visible = false;
        Main owner = (sender as Button).FindParent<Main>(); // custom extension method
        StepFinancial sf = owner.FindControl<StepFinancial>("StepFinancial1");
        sf.Argument = argument;
        sf.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

**Then lastly, and this is where my problem lies, the StepFinancial control**

```
public class StepFinancial : CompositeControl
{
    #region fields
    private TextBox _argumentTextBox;
    #endregion

    #region properties
    public string Argument { get; set; }
    #endregion

    protected override CreateChildControls()
    {
        string argument = this.Argument; // this is always null

        // I have buttons in here (not being displayed) who's events are not wiring up
        // if I move this into a method, and call the method in Render(), as it seems
        // to allow me access to the properties there, but I need the value here?
    }

    protected override Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        string argument = this.Argument; // this contains the value of the property set previously

        this._argumentTextBox.RenderControl(writer);
    }
}
```

I've tried adding the value to a StateBag, nothing. I tried adding a QueryString in the CommandEventHanlder, but get a collection is locked error message. I tried cache and Sessions (sessions won't work cause this will be deployed to SharePoint) so that's out of the question. I've tried Googling, Bing'ing even Yahoo! this but no luck.

**Update**
I failed to mention, I can't add the controls to the collection under OnPreRender as it does not wire up any of the events. I can't use EnsureChildControls either as it screws up other parts of the application. I can, however, add the value from the property at this level, to a statebag, but I feel this is a very bad way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I did not really resolve this in a matter that I would feel comfortable with, but I have a NoSQL solution underlying this, and store the values between the controls in there and dispose of it when the application closes.